# Directly update the optimizer learning rate

Tags: pytorch, learning-rate

I have a specific learning rate schedule in mind. It is based on the `epoch` but differs from the generally available ones I am aware of including `StepLR`.

Is there something that would perform the equivalent to:

`optimizer.set_lr(lr)`

or

`optimizer.set_param('lr,',lr)`

I would then simply invoke that method at the end of each `epoch` (or possibly even more frequently)

Context: I am using the `adam` optimizer as so:

```
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LrMax, weight_decay=decay) # , betas=(args.beta1, args.beta2)
```

**Update**  I found this information https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/change-learning-rate-in-pytorch/14653:

```
for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        param_group['lr'] = lr
```

Is there a way to ascertain that the `adam` optimizer being used is employing the new learning rate?

Comment: set it to a giant value mid training and watch the loss go up (if it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

```
for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
    param_group['lr'] = lr
```

Comment: Found that same resource just as you were providing the answer (updated question).  I'm running the training now with it.